# How do I save a tensorflow estimator created with tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How do I save a tensorflow estimator created with tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator?

The below is where I am at currently.

The keras model:

```
    def create_model(self):
        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Reshape((self.num_features,), input_shape=(self.num_features, 1)),
            ...
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
        ])
        model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                      loss="binary_crossentropy",
                      metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model
```

From which I create the estimator:

```
self.model = self.create_model()
self.estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=self.model)
self.serving_input_receiver_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(
tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(
    [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(self.model.input_names[0], shape=self.model.layers[0].input_shape[1:])]
))
```

Then I train the model:

```
return tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(
            estimator=self.estimator,
            train_spec=self.train_spec,
            eval_spec=self.test_spec)
```

Finally, I want to save this model:

```
self.estimator.export_saved_model(path, self.serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

This throws an error like the below. I can see that the path up to `test_output/model\temp-1599746280\variables\variables_temp_135e48a636f3441d8d35e49ff7fa2e67/` is created.

```
2020-09-10 21:58:01.338876: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1767] OP_REQUIRES failed at save_restore_v2_ops.cc:109 : Not found: Failed to create a NewWriteableFile: test_output/model\temp-1599746280\variables\variables_temp_135e48a636f3441d8d35e49ff7fa2e67/part-00000-of-00002.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate13255611844751724719 : The system cannot find the path specified.
; No such process
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question in case someone else is struggling with this. Note that I haven't got this working on a local dev environment as `tf.estimator` seems to have an issue writing to paths on my local windows environment, but it does work in SageMaker.

The code that works on SageMaker is below.

```
def __init__(..., model_dir)
...
    self.model = self.create_model()
    self.estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(
        keras_model=self.model, 
        model_dir=model_dir
    )
...

def serving_input_fn(self):
    feature_spec = {
        self.model.input_names[0]: tf.io.FixedLenFeature(
            dtype=tf.float32, 
            shape=[self.num_features]
        )
    }
    logging.debug("feature spec: %s", feature_spec)
    return tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)()

...

def save_model(self, path):
    self.estimator.export_saved_model(path, self.serving_input_fn)
```

**Note** When running locally on windows to test I need to set `model_dir = None` in `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator` and I can't save the model i.e. don't call `self.estimator.export_saved_model`